# Unable to create a dataframe from json dstream using pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, dstream

I am attempting to create a dataframe from json in dstream but the code below does not seem to get the dataframe right -

```
import sys
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
def getSqlContextInstance(sparkContext):
    if ('sqlContextSingletonInstance' not in globals()):
        globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance'] = SQLContext(sparkContext)
    return globals()['sqlContextSingletonInstance']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        raise IOError("Invalid usage; the correct format is:\nquadrant_count.py <hostname> <port>")

# Initialize a SparkContext with a name
spc = SparkContext(appName="jsonread")
sqlContext = SQLContext(spc)
# Create a StreamingContext with a batch interval of 2 seconds
stc = StreamingContext(spc, 2)
# Checkpointing feature
stc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
# Creating a DStream to connect to hostname:port (like localhost:9999)
lines = stc.socketTextStream(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
lines.pprint()
parsed = lines.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
def process(time, rdd):
    print("========= %s =========" % str(time))
    try:
        # Get the singleton instance of SQLContext
        sqlContext = getSqlContextInstance(rdd.context)
        # Convert RDD[String] to RDD[Row] to DataFrame
        rowRdd = rdd.map(lambda w: Row(word=w))
        wordsDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd)
        # Register as table
        wordsDataFrame.registerTempTable("mytable")
        testDataFrame = sqlContext.sql("select summary from mytable")
        print(testDataFrame.show())
        print(testDataFrame.printSchema())
    except:
        pass
parsed.foreachRDD(process)
stc.start()
# Wait for the computation to terminate
stc.awaitTermination()
```

No errors but when the script runs, it does read the json from streaming context successfully however it does not print the values in summary or the dataframe schema.

Example json I am attempting to read -

> {"reviewerID": "A2IBPI20UZIR0U", "asin": "1384719342", "reviewerName":
>   "cassandra tu \"Yeah, well, that's just like, u...", "helpful": [0,
>   0], "reviewText": "Not much to write about here, but it does exactly
>   what it's supposed to. filters out the pop sounds. now my recordings
>   are much more crisp. it is one of the lowest prices pop filters on
>   amazon so might as well buy it, they honestly work the same despite
>   their pricing,", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "good", "unixReviewTime":
>   1393545600, "reviewTime": "02 28, 2014"}

I am absolute new comer to spark streaming and started working on pet projects by reading documentation. Any help and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you remove the try/except statement? I'd expect an exception is raised in that block, which is not being noticed because you're just using `pass` in the except block...